# Saving grep output in csh

Tags: csh

Hi I just started to do some csh scripting and I have been having issues with storing grep results to a variable.  I'm trying to save a line from a file that contains a username as a substring.

```
echo `grep -w $name /etc/passwd`
set line=`grep -w $name /etc/passwd`
echo $line
```

The first line is just a debug line so I know my grep is getting the correct line.  Its the second line that is giving me issues.  When I echo it it prints "echo: no match".  Anyone have any help to offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your passwd file contains an `*`.  Add double quotes to your script:

```
set line="`grep -w $name /etc/passwd`"
echo "$line"
```

Without the quotes, the `*` gets interpreted as a wildcard file match character that [probably] won't match any real file.

Comment: You're quite welcome.  Nowadays, I write 99.44% of my scripts in perl.  But, before that, I used csh exclusively [and it's _still_ my login shell].  It's nice to see a few people still using csh

Comment: set line=$(grep -w $name /etc/passwd) is better, since it is more readable, and allows nested commands. `cmnd1 ` cmd2 `` ends at second backtick.

Comment: @ArifBurhan Uh, no. This is for `csh` and _not_ `bash` et. al. `csh` has _no_ such construct [and its syntax is completely different from `sh` derivatives]